# Update Global Component data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am updating this with my new code. I need to get a reference to the "allImages" property of the data object within the dropzones "onSuccess" method. Is there any way to do it.

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form action="/user/album_images" id="dropzone" class="dropzone" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" id="album_id" name="album_id" :value=image.id>
            </form>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="image in albumImages">
        <img src="https://mysite.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/users/62MY43og3ZNCLU4y53iwoqdEfUZUWFEfDM2f9krn.png" class="img-responsive" style="width: 120px; height: 90px;">

        </div>
    </div>


</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    props: ['theImage','theAlbumImages'],
     data() {
        return {
        image: this.theImage,
        albumImages: this.theAlbumImages

        }
     },


        methods: {

        },




    }
 let csrfToken = document.querySelectorAll('meta[name=csrf-token]')[0].getAttributeNode('content').value
    Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 10, // MB
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        init: function() {
            this.on("success", function(file,albumImage) {

               // I want to get a reference to the vue instances "albumImages" property


            });
        },
        headers: {
            'x-csrf-token': csrfToken
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [vue-script2](https://github.com/taoeffect/vue-script2)

You will be able to access vue variables like in template.

```
<script2>
....
 this.on("success", function(file,albumImage) {

              var x = {{albumImages}}


            });
....
</script2>
```

Although it might not work. Other option would be to try load function in mounted. E.g.

```
import VS2 from 'vue-script2'
export default {
  name: 'freshchat',
  mounted() {
    VS2.load('yourdropzonejs script').then(() => {
           var vm = this
           .....
           this.on("success", function(file,albumImage) {

               vm.albumImages


            });

    })
  }
}
```